# are the kinds of

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, singular

a. Those are the kind of bird that live around this marsh and mate in the summer.

b. Those are the kinds of birds that live around this marsh and mate in the summer.

c. Those are the kind of birds that live around this marsh and mate in the summer.

If they all belong to the same species, which of the above sentences should be used?
There are a number of birds, but they are all the same kind.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either a or c are all right. b is perfectly understandable, but technically refers to more than one kind of bird; if the collection of birds is all of one species, then you have only one kind.

I think it would also be all right, and possibly a little better, to say "That is the kind of bird...", taking the subject of the sentence as the kind of bird instead of the collection of birds.